# Can the effectiveness of a heat sink be increased with surface texturing?

Tags: thermodynamics, cooling

Some supercapacitors use chemical etching to increase their surface area by several orders of magnitude. Could a similar process be used on a heat sink to increase its surface area and thus its ability to dissipate heat?

Comment: yes, why do you think some microprocessors have those weird heat sinks? see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_sink

Comment: The fins can be optimized for heat exchange with the surrounding air, to reduce air resistance and noise. For a purely radiative heat sink (as used on spacecraft), the surface just has to be "black enough", but structuring the surface beyond that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @julianfernandez I should have been more clear, I meant microscopic texturing, not large fins.